# Is this red solid/gummy stuff bad transmission fluid? If not, what might it be?

Tags: dodge, leak, transmission-fluid, grand-caravan

I noticed some red solid/gummy substance underneath my vehicle on the passenger side today.  It is on the colored portion of the exterior that wraps underneath the vehicle.  See the first photo below.  Looking around, I also noticed some of what appears to be the same substance on the (sway bar?) of my vehicle, also on the passenger side (second photo below, near the middle of the photo).  I have a 2013 Dodge Grand Caravan.

What might this be?  Is this transmission fluid gone horribly bad and leaking?  Or is it some more benign grease leaking out from somewhere?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it's gummy and red it's probably grease. Many times a CV axle boot will be damaged and allow grease to spray out during high rpms. Check the CV boot for damage. If the boot is damaged it can be replaced as long as the CV joint is good. But if you continue to drive with a damaged boot, the joint will soon fail.

Comment: I've never seen red CVJ grease. Most CVJ grease I've ever seen is black or near black. This looks like spooge from a grease zirk that a mechanic didn't clean up after greasing a ball joint or tie rod end.

Comment: I agree. I've never seen red in boot neither. Your suggestion does make much more sense.

Comment: I've seen filled motor and transmission mounts ooze out like that, although the position of the leaked goop does not really support it.   I agree with @Paulster2

Comment: @paulster2 you should add that in your answer.. that's really good explanation 